# jq - Use regex in the json in test function

Tags: regex, jq

I have some json that contains regex

```
[
  {
     "name": "For teachers",
     "regex": "^Apple "
  },
  {
     "name": "Long and yellow",
     "regex": "banana$"
  },
  {
     "name": "Cantaloupe",
     "regex": ".*/melon/.*"
  }
]
```

What I wanted to do is use the `.regex` value in the test function e.g.

```
>>> jq '. | select( "path/to/melon/data" | test( .regex ) )' test.json
jq: error (at test.json:14): Cannot index string with string "regex"
```

I am trying to check if a string, passed in anyhow, matches any of the `.regex` in the json and if it does return the corresponding `.name`.

In the above `test.json`, passing a string => output:

- starting "Apples " => "For teachers"
- ending "banana" => "Long and yellow"
- containing the text "/melons/" => "Canteloupe"

If there are multiple matches then return all the `.name` values where the `.regex` matches the passed in string. So from the comments:
"Apple or Is this /melon/ a banana" => [ "For teachers", "Long and yellow", "Canteloupe" ]

---

I was considering trying something like building a sed command but I have not got that far and I think adding what I had was causing confusion rather than clarifying. Leaving it here so the comments make sense.

```
>>> echo "path/to/melon/data" | sed -E -e 's#^Apple #For teachers #g' -e 's#banana$#long and yellow#g' -e 's#.*/melon/.*#Cantaloupe#g'
Cantaloupe
>>> echo "Is this banana" | sed -E -e 's#^Apple #For teachers#g' -e 's#banana$#long and yellow#g' -e 's#.*/melon/.*#Cantaloupe#g'
Is this long and yellow
```

I want a behaviour similar to this sed, but without me needing to construct lots of `-e` options from `jq` print.

I am sure I can get something like that to work, so every time the echoed in string matches a `.regex` it returns the corresponding `.name` but that is such a hack ... even for me! (Note: This sed is not doing what I want except in the melon case, because it is replacing the text matched rather than responding with the text)

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines. Does "test.json" contain the sample JSON shown?  The `sed` commands perform transformations, which `test` obviously does not do, so please clarify the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `--raw-input` (or `-R`) option to read in the string, and the `--argfile` option to read in the regex JSON file:

```bash
echo "path/to/melon/data" |
jq -Rr --argfile rs regex.json '
  $rs[] as $r
  | if test($r.regex) then $r.name else empty end
'
```

```
Cantaloupe
```

If the string is contained somewhere in your input JSON, you obviously don't need the `--raw-input` (or `-R`) option:

```bash
jq -r --argfile rs regex.json '
  ...traverse to the string... | $rs[] as $r
  | if test($r.regex) then $r.name else empty end
' input.json
```

Comment: This will output "long and yellow" for the input "Is this banana", but it should output "Is this long and yellow" (from what I understand).

Comment: @knittl It's not entirely clear what or how the OP wants to postprocess in case of a match, so I stayed with their `test` approach which can easily be modified to `gsub`, for instance.

Comment: The sed example ("so that is has a behaviour similar to this sed") performs substitution.

Comment: @knittl Unless stated explicitly, I'm trying to make as few assumptions as possible. Of course, the OP can always clarify their requirements, so I can adapt my response accordingly.

Comment: This looks good will try tomorrow and get back

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to apply your array of regexes in turn to your input string. In other words: [reducing](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Reduce) your input by aggregating the results of a substitution operation.

```
reduce $regex[0][] as $re (.; gsub($re.regex; $re.name))
```

Provide `$regex` via `--slurpfile` and make sure to read raw input (`-R`) and write raw output (`-r`):

```
$ echo "Is this banana" | jq -Rr --slurpfile regex test.json 'reduce $regex[0][] as $re (.; gsub($re.regex; $re.name))'
Is this Long and yellow
```

All substitutions are applied:

```
$ echo "Apple or Is this melon a banana" | jq -Rr --slurpfile regex test.json 'reduce $regex[0][] as $re (.; gsub($re.regex; $re.name))'
For teahcersor Is this melon a Long and yellow
```

And would be applied to already-substituted strings. So if you had `"^a"`=>`"x"` and `"x"`=>`"y"`, then the input `"abc"` would end up as `"ybc"`.

```
$ echo "Apple or Is this /melon/ a banana" | jq -Rr --slurpfile regex test.json 'reduce $regex[0][] as $re (.; gsub($re.regex; $re.name))'
Cantaloupe
```

---

And if you only want to print the first substitution which is possible, the following could work (although I'm sure there's a smarter way, this looks way to convoluted):

```
$ echo "Apple or Is this /melon/ a banana" | jq -Rr --slurpfile regex test.json '
. as $in 
| $regex[0] 
| map(
  . as $re
  | $in
  | select(test($re.regex))
  | gsub($re.regex; $re.name)
) 
| first
'
For teahcersor Is this /melon/ a banana
```

---

After the updates to the question, here's an answer to the last version:

```
$ echo "Apple or Is this /melon/ a banana" | jq -Rr --slurpfile regex test.json '
. as $in 
| $regex[0] 
| map(
  select(. as $re | $in | test($re.regex))
  | .name
)
'
[
  "For teahcers",
  "Long and yellow",
  "Cantaloupe"
]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate reduce as well and pick my favourite. I have updated my question to clarify my expected output. It got late and I rushed it, sorry.